# How obtain a line from a text file based in the id of the line?

Tags: php, file, sap-gui

I have a host name which I read from `saplogon.ini` file. 
Now, I load this file into an array say `$lines`.

When I read the host name by `$hostname = $lines[10]`; 
I cannot log in but if I hard code value as `$line = "host name";` and then assign it to hostname, `$hostname = $line`, then it works fine.

Any body has any solution to this? To make my program dynamic I need to read this value from saplogon.ini and use explode to get desired name.

Here is snippet of my code:

```
$pieces = explode('=', $line, 2);
elseif(!isset($ASHOST))   $ASHOST = $pieces[1];
elseif(!isset($SYSNO)) $SYSNO = $pieces[1];
```

Funny thing is it does not cause any problem for $SYSNO though I get it by same logic.

Here is my saplogon.ini snippet

```
[Server]
Item1=cesdsbop01.vco.bpcoco
Item2=192.168.1.198
Item3=cesapplpt1
Item4=cesderlpt01.vco.bpcoco
Item5=cesderlpt03.vco.bpcoco
Item5=00
Item6=cesperlpt01.vco.bpcoco
Item7=cesqerlpt01.vco.bpcoco
Item8=cesderlpt02.vco.bpcoco
Item9=cespilpt.vco.bpcoco


[Database]
Item1=00
Item2=01
Item3=00
Item4=00
Item5=00
Item6=00
Item7=00
Item8=00
Item9=01
```

Does not work, though I was trying to do the same thing, but added FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES as well. I tried IP address for hostname, same thing. Sorry I do not know how to format this code below.

```
$line = "Item5=cesderlpt03.vco.bpcoco";
$CLIENT = "210";
$system = "Item5";
$a["USER"] = "Adarsh";
$handle = "saplogon.ini";
$lines = file($handle, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$line = $lines[0];
echo $lines[0];
$pieces = explode('=', $line, 2);
if(!isset($ASHOST))  { $ASHOST = $pieces[1];}
$line = $lines[1];
$pieces = explode('=', $lines[1], 2);
if(!isset($SYSNO)){ $SYSNO = $pieces[1];}

function sap_login($ASHOST, $SYSNO, $CLIENT, $USER)
{
$l["ASHOST"] = $ASHOST; //"cesderpap03.uhi.amerco";
$l["SYSNR"] = $SYSNO;
$l["CLIENT"] = $CLIENT;
$l["USER"] = $USER;
$l["PASSWD"] = "adarsh123";
if (isset($GWHOST))     $l["GWHOST"] = $GWHOST;              //             
if (isset($GWSERV))             $l["GWSERV"] =  $GWSERV;
$l["MSHOST"] = "";
$l["R3NAME"] = "ECD";
$l["GROUP"] = "";
$l["LANG"] = "EN";
$l["TRACE"] = "";       //if (isset($TRACE))        $TRACE;                   
$l["LCHECK"] = "";      //if (isset($LCHECK))       $LCHECK;                    
$l["CODEPAGE"] = "1160";    //if (isset($CODEPAGE))     $CODEPAGE;


$sap = @saprfc_open ($l);
saprfc_set_code_page ($sap,$l["CODEPAGE"]);
if(! $sap)
{
echo saprfc_error($sap);
}
else {echo "connected";}
}
sap_login(&$ASHOST, &$SYSNO, &$CLIENT, &$a["USER"])
?>
```

This code let's me login to SAP. That is what I am trying to achieve. If i don't choose to do, `$line = $lines[0];` my code works fine because then it is using the hard coded value from the first line `$line = "Item5=cesderlpt03.vco.bpcoco";`

So based in the name of item I need the line where the Item is placed. As example if I chose `Item5` I want retrive the line of my .ini file where the text `Item5=cesderlpt03.vco.bpcoco` is located.

Comment: edit with the content of your saplogon.ini

Comment: I post my answer, if you edit with more code I can see exactly what do you want do

Comment: Edit with the whole code that works for you and explain what do you want obtain

Comment: if your code works what do you want?

Comment: My hard coded code works not the dynamic one. I want to make my code more flexible so I do not have to add values later if saplogon.ini gets changed.

Comment: ok, but how you know which is the servername by the item? For example, you want obtain the server in the Item5?

Comment: Yes, you can say that because I am using it for test purpose. You are right, it could be anything else also depending upon what user has opted on the webpage. For test purpose, I am using this one.

Comment: wait a minute, I working in this

Comment: See my code, correct your code and don't forget check my answer as correct ;-)

Comment: Thanks for trying Adrian, but this does not work. I tried all kind of things like 'fgets($lines)' but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want capture **cesderlpt03.vco.bpcoco** with the id `Item5` this code you can do it:

```
<?php

function array_find($needle, $haystack)
{
   foreach ($haystack as $item)
   {
      if (strpos($item, $needle) !== FALSE)
      {
         return $item;
         break;
      }
   }
}

$handle = "saplogon.ini";
$system = "Item5";

$lines = file($handle, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$line = array_find($system, $lines);

echo $line; 

?>
```

Comment: @Adarsh really what do you want as output?

Comment: I need the host name to login to SAP system with rfc, but when I pick it up from the saplogon.ini by using $lines[0] stuff; it rejects my input but accepts the same value as hard coded.Here is the log in to SAP code:          $sap = @saprfc_open ($l);
saprfc_set_code_page ($sap,$l["CODEPAGE"]);                                      $l is an array which contains hostname, password, client, username etc.

Comment: @Adarsh you want found into the .ini file the value cesderlpt03.vco.bpcoco?

Comment: Yes, value is found but saprfc_open rejects it, that's what I want to know, why? It accepts the same hard coded value from first line.

Comment: @Adarsh see my edit and try with my example you will see the name of the server as output, then put the code into your code. If you need some help leave a comment

Comment: Yes, I do see the output and your logic is correct but again, when I put it's value in $ASHOST, function saprfc_open rejects it.

Comment: @Adarsh I edit my code, try now ;-)

Comment: I don't see any difference, it says it was edited 34 minutes ago.

Comment: i tried now it returns the whole line 'Item5=servername' but I have to explode it and then again same problem. echo part is fine; even in the error it shows right server name but won't log in to SAP.

Comment: @Adarsh you says that when your code have $line = "Item5=cesderlpt03.vco.bpcoco"; it works how is posible that don't works with my example if the output is the same Item5=cesderlpt03.vco.bpcoco

Comment: Yes, Adrian it does not work. Even I am surprised. But I got it working otherway as $lines = file_get_contents('./saplogon.ini'). Here it returns a string not an array and I use strpos to find the right data and it works.

Comment: I appreciate a lot your hard work. Thank you so much !!

Comment: ok buddy, now I tell you the real reason why it did not work. When I calculated the length of pieces[1], it was returning 2 more than actual and it was taking space in and when I passed that parameter to saprfc_open; it blew up but now I reduce length by 2 and your method works fine.

Comment: @Adarsh finally the code works ;-)